# Posting question and answer for information purposes

Tags: discussion

I love this place, but almost solely as a spectator. Many of my questions are too vague or meandering for SE, such as "What should I name my domain" or "How do I make Exchange work?"

However, example - I recently installed Exchange 2016 on a test domain. Then removed it. Then played around with ADSIedit, tanked the Exchange Server altogether, then later tried to install it again. As you can imagine, this was interesting. And I would like to post something explaining about installing Exchange on a damaged AD domain. Not necessarily asking a question, but not necessarily stating that X + Y = Z.

This sort of post belongs on a blog, but I don't have one. Is there a place for this sort of post on SE? Such as asking the question "Can I install Exchange on a domain which previously had Exchange?" and then posting a long meandering answer about the problems I faced?

If not, any suggestions for where to document this sort of thing for public consumption would be welcome.

Comment: In general self answering and thereby contributing to the public knowledge is encouraged. - Although the above scenario sounds more like the kind of issues you would only face in lab environments and not so much in production environments and therefore not quite topical, but I can be mistaken for  I'm more an open Source guy

Comment: Even if I use SF I have also a free wordpress site for such blog post. SF is good for Q/A, but for a blog I prefer a blogging platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, asking and answering your own question is fine.

But regardless of whether you have your own answer ready, a question that requires "a long meandering answer" is probably going to be a problem.  Your example (for example), sounds like it could fall under a couple close reasons, too broad or not reasonable practices.  It sounds like an interesting situation, but I think there are too many ways you could get a messed up AD that you'd have to cover.

If you can focus your post to be more specific, then I think it's possible to have a blog-ish "look what I found out" style of question that's ok.  For example, I think this Q&A of mine falls into the "check out this surprising thing" category: [How many FSMO roles are there?](https://serverfault.com/questions/771606/how-many-fsmo-roles-are-there)